# How to use apartment gem for saas app on localhost without lvh.me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, saas

How to implement tentant to go to url like:

```
localhost:3000/tenent1
```

instead of using lvh or any domain or subdomain like:

```
http://tenent1.lvh.me:3000
tenent1.example.com
```

or

```
tenent1.com
```

where tenent1 is one of the tenent created by user on the signup process. I dont want to use subdomain, domain.

Comment: Feel free to upvote/like if it helped you. as well as future SO users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Apartment` gem has an initializer file where you can create any kind of elevator you want. I guesss you don't want the subdomain one, so you can write an elevator that would check first route part (e.g. `localhost:3000/tenant1/`)

For more info see `Apartment` intializer file.

I guess in your case it would be something like this (add this in your apartment initializer file)

```
 Rails.application.config.middleware.use 'Apartment::Elevators::Generic', lambda { |request|
   request.path.split('/')[1] # First element will be an empty string
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you want to like this routes but you can try this like:-

```
get 'tenent:id', to: 'example_controller#example_action' as: :tenent
```

so it will genrate url like this :-

```
tenent GET    /tenent:id(.:format)  example_controller#example_action
```

At this point you would need to provide dynamic id with this path like so-

```
tenent_path(id: 1)
```

in browser it will generate exactly same url that you wanted:_

```
localhost:3000/teanent1
```

and at controller side you can access this id in `params[:id]`